# Django | Registro de usuario no guarda nuevo usuario

Tags: django

El registrar nuevo usuario, el formulario se muestra bien, pero no se guarda o crea el nuevo usuario. Parece que es el request el que no devuelve los datos del formulario. Si pongo un print dentro del def registro(request) no sale. Es decir, parece que no entra en la función.

**El formulario se muestra bien:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Forms.py**

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email','password1','password2']
```

**Views.py**

```
class UserRegistrationView(FormView):
template_name = "registration/user_registration.html"
form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
print("12341827643981726498761239487691287346928746")
success_url = reverse_lazy('home_app:home')

def post(self, request):
    print("Dentro de post...09238470928374092837409283740928374")
    form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data['username']
    args = {'form': form, 'text':text}
    return render(request, 'registration/user_registration.html', args)
```

Terminal (muestra que se ha entrado en **def post** sin problema):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mis conocimientos de Django son muy recientes y aún algo tiernos, pero a bote pronto yo diría que si estás utilizando clases para definir las vistas deberías utilizar una `CreateView` que además te ahorra tener que definir cómo se crea el objeto.

```
class UserRegistrationView(CreateView):
    template_name = "users/user_registration.html"
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    model = CustomUser  # especifica tu modelo de usuario, o User
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home_app:home')
```

con esas simples líneas Django crea el objeto CustomUser sin necesidad de explicarle nada más.

Comment: Gracias, así es, con Createview funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Como ha comentado Sokkian, hay que utilizar CreateView. Almenos utilizándolo funciona bien:

```
class UserRegistrationView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'registration/user_registration.html'
    model = User
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = 'home'
```